# How to escape / char in grep -P '(?!.*//)word' to escape comments

Tags: regex, linux, grep

`grep -P '(?!.*//)word'` i learnt to exclude a pattern in grep using `grep -P` with perl regex. but i don't know how to exclude `//`

i tried

- `/`
- `\/`
- `\\/`

nothing seems to work

Comment: `/` isn't special.. can you show some sample input lines and exact output needed for those lines? Does it work if you use `grep -P '^(?!.*//).*word'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```sh
grep -P '^\s*//.*(*SKIP)(*F)|word' file
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/qiFMsf/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```sh
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //                       '//'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(*SKIP)(*F)               skip and proceed searching for the next pattern
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  word                     'word'
```